# AWS Cognito federated signin 'build' environment issue

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have been trying to solve this over a week now and can't seem to find out the root cause.

**Issue** : When using AWS Cognito federated signin on AWS Amplify build env, this throws error. However it works completely fine on my localhost. I have also checked the configurations. Please note that this is WITHOUT `Hosted UI`, I am using my own UI for this. I have hosted the app on `AWS Amplify`.

**Tech Stack** : `Angular 9` `AWS Cognito`

[image: Error]

[image: configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so whoever happen to come across this error the main issue is that `AWS Amplify` does not check `aws config` file by default, hence if you update the config manually it will not work.

Please make sure to update 'Cognito auth' via `CLI` only.And publish the changes, it will work.